# Error deserializing json array nullpointer exception

Tags: apex, json, error, deserialize, null-pointer

I receive this json through a request

```
{"pay_CCIban":"XXX",
"pay_bic":"YYY",
"pay_names[]":["name one","name two"],
"pay_extid":"extId"}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it with this class

```
global class Famrs{
    global class datajsonweb{
       global String pay_CCIban {get; set;}
       global String pay_bic {get; set;}
       global List<String> pay_names {get; set;}
       global String pay_extid {get; set;}
    }
    datajsonweb data = (datajsonweb)JSON.deserialize(requestBody.toString(),datajsonweb.class);
    Integer lstSize = data.pay_names.size(); //I get nullpointer here
    ...
}
```

I get an attempt to de-reference null object when I try to get the size of the array inside the json, i don't know what I'm doing wrong

Any help?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Like sfdcfox says, the "pay_names[]" key in the json needs to be like "pay_names" so I'm trying to do a replaceAll('[]','') but I'm getting: Invalid regex: Unclosed character class. If I try to escape the brackets I get: Illegal string literal.

Is it possible to remove the brackets in the json?

Thanks again

EDIT 2:

Thanks to Jesse Milburn's comment it works.

Comment: Are you sure that every `json` object contains data for that field? Or even contains that field? If the field is empty (or doesn't exist) the deserializer will not instantiate an empty list.

Comment: Yes completely sure, I get all data correct except for this: "pay_names[]":["name one","name two"],

Comment: Why does your `pay_names` json variable is called `"pay_names[]"`? Shouldn't it be `"pay_names"`?

Comment: I think that too, but I receive pay_names[]

Comment: \\\[\\\] should be your escape.

Comment: Yasss it Jesse comment works thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[]` in your JSON won't work. The parser would try to map this to an apex variable named `pay_names[]`. This is not a valid *Apex* identifier. Valid identifiers in Apex must start with a letter, can only include letters, numbers, and underscores, can't have two consecutive underscores, and can't be certain reserved keywords. JSON.deserialize does not automatically map things like `[]` to the nearest valid identifier.

In order to use a JSON class, your JSON would need to be:

```
{"pay_CCIban":"XXX",
"pay_bic":"YYY",
"pay_names":["name one","name two"],
"pay_extid":"extId"}
```

If you want to use the JSON exactly as is, use an explicit parser, or use JSON.deserializeUntyped, or JSON.Parser.

Comment: I think that too, I'm trying now to make a replaceAll('[]','') to remove the brackets in pay_names but I'm getting invalid regex: Unclosed character class near index 2 ].... Updated question